# VBA: hide and unhide code not working

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and have been trying to write a code that hides and unhides rows based on the input value of a certain cell address. However, it doesn't work and I don't why. I have posted my code below:

```
Sub Hide()

If Worksheets("IS").Range("B8").Value = "Show All" Then
   Worksheets("IS").Rows("12:165").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

If Worksheets("IS").Range("B8").Value = "Just Revenue" Then
   Worksheets("IS").Rows("12:165").EntireRow.Hidden = False
   Worksheets("IS").Rows("28:165").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

If Worksheets("IS").Range("B8").Value = "Just Expenses" Then
   Worksheets("IS").Rows("12:165").EntireRow.Hidden = False
   Worksheets("IS").Rows("12:27").EntireRow.Hidden = True
   Worksheets("IS").Rows("160:165").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

If Worksheets("IS").Range("B8").Value = "Just Cogs" Then
   Worksheets("IS").Rows("12:165").EntireRow.Hidden = False
   Worksheets("IS").Rows("12:27").EntireRow.Hidden = True
   Worksheets("IS").Rows("64:165").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

If Worksheets("IS").Range("B8").Value = "Just Totals" Then
   Worksheets("IS").Rows("12:165").EntireRow.Hidden = False
   Worksheets("IS").Rows("12:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
   Worksheets("IS").Rows("28:61").EntireRow.Hidden = True
   Worksheets("IS").Rows("64:91").EntireRow.Hidden = True
   Worksheets("IS").Rows("93:155").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```

Any help with why my code doesn't work or any tips to improve it would be much appreciative.

Comment: When you change the value in B8, how do you execute this subroutine? It won't execute by itself. You have to push a button or attach to a worksheet event or run it manually or something.

Comment: I have a list on the cell B8 (through Data Validation) which has the drop down options Show all, Just revenues ..etc

Comment: But how does the code execute. Is there a button, do you go into VBE and hit the "Play" button or F5? What happens when you manually run the code after setting the drop down?

Comment: There is no button; the goal was to have this run all the time so everytime some changes the value in B8 the correct rows hide. Is that not possible?

Comment: Well, if you want it to run anytime something changes, you could try calling this sub from the worksheet_change event...

Comment: Ive never used worksheet_change would you mind writing a line or two just to see how it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewriting for Worksheet_Change:

In your VBE, paste this code into the code sheet for the "IS" worksheet (double click it in the `Project - VBAProject` pane. If the `Project - VBAProject` pane is not visible in your VBE, go to `View`>>`Project Explorer`):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Ensure that we don't trigger another change event while this code is running
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Check if cell B8 triggered this change:
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B8")) Is Nothing Then

       'B8 changed... which means B8 is "Target" variable
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "Show All"
                Worksheets("IS").Rows("12:165").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case "Just Revenue"
                Worksheets("IS").Rows("12:165").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Worksheets("IS").Rows("28:165").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case "Just Expenses"
                Worksheets("IS").Rows("12:165").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Worksheets("IS").Rows("12:27").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Worksheets("IS").Rows("160:165").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case "Just Cogs"
                Worksheets("IS").Rows("12:165").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Worksheets("IS").Rows("12:27").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Worksheets("IS").Rows("64:165").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case "Just Totals"
                Worksheets("IS").Rows("12:165").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Worksheets("IS").Rows("12:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Worksheets("IS").Rows("28:61").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Worksheets("IS").Rows("64:91").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Worksheets("IS").Rows("93:155").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End Select
    End If

    'Turn events back on so this code triggers again
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

There are quite a few events that we can hook VBA to (SelectionChange, DoubleClick, Workbook_Close, etc). In this case we are hooking to `Worksheet_Change()`.

This code gets triggered every time this worksheet experiences a change. The `Target` variable will hold the range that triggered the event. So we test to see if that `Target` intersects with `Range("B8")` which means `B8` was changed. Then we perform the code inside the `If` block.

I switched your `If/ElseIf` over to a `Select/Case` just because it makes for cleaner code since we are testing a single condition (the value of B8) over and over again.

In this code we also toggle off the Excel Applications `EnableEvents` feature. This feature is what allowed this `Worksheet_Change()` to get triggered in the first place. Often times in the code we make more changes to the worksheet (hiding rows or columns, for instance) which will trigger the application to run `Worksheet_Change()` again... while it's running `Worksheet_Change()` already. This can cause code to run superfluously and, often, cause an endless loop that makes excel crash.

Comment: Thank you so much! The code works perfectly and you also helped me understand whats going on in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This code needs to be pasted on the sheet where you want are wanting to execute the code. You will not need to qualify your ranges  with the sheets once the code is there as well.

You can just refer directly to your range without the `Worksheets("IS").` as so:
 `Rows("so and so").EntireRow.Hidden = True`

You can also just refer to your `TargetRange` by variable now like so:
`If MyTarget = "Just Revenue" Then`

I inserted one of your conditions in the code as an example

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

Dim MyTarget As Range
Set MyTarget = Range("B8")

If Not Intersect(target, MyTarget) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Your CODE HERE
If MyTarget = "Show All" Then
Rows("12:165").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```